# Match two arrays to get value from second array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays.

`$queue_ids` and `$subscriber_results`.

`$queue_ids` outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 )
```

`$subscriber_results` outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [email] => test1@test.com [subscribed] => 1436264818 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [email] => test2@test.com [subscribed] => 1436265909 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 5 [email] => test3@test.com [subscribed] => 1436265919 ) )
```

I need to match the two arrays to get the `email` record for those keys in the `$queue_ids` array, from the `$subscriber_results` array.

I tried using array_keys() but couldn't get it to work.

Is anyone able to show me how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use in_array for this . try to use above code

```
<?php
$matched=array();
foreach($subscriber_results as $key=>$val)
{
    if(in_array($val['id'],$queue_ids))
    {
        $matched[]=$val['email'];
    }

}
print_r($matched);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) to extract an array where id is array index (key) and the email is the value. Then [compare it](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) to the list of queue ids [flipped](http://php.net/array_flip) so the values are the indexes (keys).

```
$matchingEmails = array_intersect_key(array_column($subscriber_results, "email", "id"), array_flip($queue_ids));
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am not using PHP 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk` along with `in_array` as

```
$result = array();
array_walk($subscriber_results,function($v,$k)use(&$result,$queue_ids){
    if(in_array($v['id'],$queue_ids)){
        $result[] = $v['email'];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First get all matching records in your `$subscriber_results` from `$queue_ids` by `array_filter()`

```
$matches = array_filter($subscriber_results, function($v) use ($queue_ids){
            return in_array($v['id'], $queue_ids);
        });
```

Then, get column named `email` using `array_column()`

```
$matches = array_column($matches, 'email');
```

Now, `$matches` will contain emails with `id` in `$queue_ids`

---

You can also club them, by

```
$matches = array_column(array_filter($subscriber_results, function($v) use ($queue_ids){
            return in_array($v['id'], $queue_ids);
        }), 'email');
```